# Checking/Iterating Multi-dimensional arrays in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have the following array:

```
{
  quiztitle: "Name the US Presidents",
  presidents: [
        {
          president_name: "George Washington",
          number: "1",
          imgurl: "c-1gw.jpg",
          answer_variations: [
                              "Washington"
                             ]
         },
         {
          president_name: "John Quincy Adams",
          number: "6",
          imgurl: "c-6ja.jpg",
          answer_variations: [
                               "Adams",
                               "John Adams"
                             ]
          }, .... ect
```

How do I access the answer variations array and compare the contents against a submitted value?

I currently have this code for checking the presidents:

```
var answer = $('.presidentRow input').val().toLowerCase();
var correct = false; 
$.each(data.presidents, function(i, president) {
if ( president.number == questionNumber && president.president_name.toLowerCase() === answer) {
                            correct = true;
                            return false;
                        }
                    });
```

This code takes the question number and checks the users submitted value against the presidents name. If its correct it sets the variable true and I can work with that to produce a result. How can I check the submitted answer against the variations aswell?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another way of compare you can try~

```
var answer = $('.presidentRow input').val().toLowerCase();
var correct = false;
$.each(data.presidents, function(i, president) {
    if ( president.number == questionNumber) {
        if(president.president_name.toLowerCase() === answer){
            correct = true;
        }else if((','+ president.answer_variations.join().toLowerCase()+',').indexOf(','+answer+',')!=-1){
            correct = true;
        }
        return false;
    }
});
```

**EDIT**

Use `Array.join()` make variations as coma seperated string and you can simple use `String.indexOf()` to check if the answer exists or not.

Add `','` make the answer will fit the correct variations option.

Comment: This worked, could you explain your answer for me please

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a list to hold the names and its all variations in lowercase. Use [$.merge](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.merge/) to create list, then use [$.map](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.map/) to form them to lowercase.
2. If the answer is any of them, answer is correct. Use [$.inArray](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.hasData/) to find the index, and if index >= 0, the answer is in the list, so its correct.

```
var answer = $('.presidentRow input').val().toLowerCase();
var questionNumber = $('#qNum').val();
var correct = false; 
$.each(data.presidents, function(i, president) {
  if ( president.number == questionNumber) {
    // Put all possible name answers into an array.
    var nameVairations = 
      $.merge([president.president_name], president.answer_variations);

    // .toLowercase all answers
    nameVairations = $.map(nameVairations, function(name) {
      return name.toLowerCase();
    });

    // Check if the answer appears in the list
    if ($.inArray(answer, nameVairations) >= 0) {
      correct = true;
      return false;
    }
  }
});
```

You can also achieve the same result with vanilla js array functions [.concat](https://developer.mozilla.org/zh-TW/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat), [.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), [.indexOf](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf)

Comment: All answers are being returned false, could you have another look?

Comment: Do you have a jsfiddle for test? Or I'll create one to check it.

Comment: I do not have a fiddle sorry

Comment: @Dale updated, forget to put `nameVairations` as map's first param, now it works.

Answer (score 0):

So basically, iterate the presidents array until we find that the number of its president is equal to the question number. Then test the answer against the president name, if not... try to find it in the answer_variations arrray.

```
var answer = $('.presidentRow input').val().toLowerCase();
var presidents = data.presidents;
var correct = presidents.some(function(president) {
    if (president.number == questionNumber) {
      if (answer == president.president_name.toLowerCase()) {
        return true;
      } else {
        return president.answer_variations.some(function(validAnswer) {
          console.log(validAnswer.toLowerCase());
          if (answer == validAnswer.toLowerCase()) {
            return true;
          }
        });
      }
    }
  });
```

I don't know how you get questionNumber.

**Small Test**

```js
var data = {
  quiztitle: "Name the US Presidents",
  presidents: [{
    president_name: "George Washington",
    number: "1",
    imgurl: "c-1gw.jpg",
    answer_variations: [
      "Washington"
    ]
  }, {
    president_name: "John Quincy Adams",
    number: "6",
    imgurl: "c-6ja.jpg",
    answer_variations: [
      "Adams",
      "John Adams"
    ]
  }]
};

function presidentTest(answer, questionNumber) {
  var answer = answer.toLowerCase();
  return data.presidents.some(function(president) {
    if (president.number == questionNumber) {
      if (answer == president.president_name.toLowerCase()) {
        return true;
      } else {
        return president.answer_variations.some(function(validAnswer) {
          console.log(validAnswer.toLowerCase());
          if (answer == validAnswer.toLowerCase()) {
            return true;
          }
        });
      }
    }
  });
}

/**** TEST *****/
document.getElementById('results').innerHTML += '\n' + presidentTest('george Washington', 1);
document.getElementById('results').innerHTML += '\n' + presidentTest('wachington', 1);
document.getElementById('results').innerHTML += '\n' + presidentTest('adams', 6);
document.getElementById('results').innerHTML += '\n' + presidentTest('john adams', 6);
```

```html
<pre id="results"></pre>
```

Comment: Question number is set when a user clicks on a question to answer

Answer (score 0):

```
var answer = answer.toLowerCase().replace(/\s+/," ") // replace multiple spaces by single space and lower the case
var correct = false; 
var president = data.presidents.find(function(president){return president.number == questionNumber;})
if(president){
   var variationsArr = president.answer_variations.concat([president.president_name])
   correct = ("|" + variationsArr.join("|").toLowerCase() + "|").indexOf("|" + answer + "|") > -1; 
}
```